# Facebook Open Graph Debugger return 503 for my Wordpress Site

Tags: facebook, wordpress

When I trr to share an article from my wordpress site (http://rougeotbeaunetriathlon.com/triathlon-de-dijon.html) on facebook it does not work.

If I try to debug using OpenGraph Debugger I received Error 503.

My Service provider tell me issue is not from his side. Also from his side, when he try debugger it is working....

I have try from other computers and place : same issue ....

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mena by it "does not work" and how you are debugging it. Please edit your Q and update your Q.

Comment: That url doesn't load for me at all.

Comment: Hello,

thank you for your help

By "does not work", I mean : when you past the url of an article in facebook, a preview of the article should appear. In my case it does not. But it is not surprising as I receive error 503 in debugger....

From your side, you cannot reach at all my website in your browser? (http://rougeotbeaunetriathlon.com) 

This could explain why facebook debugger return 503 ...